# A question regarding inflection points of a function

Tags: calculus

Is it possible for a point c to be inflection (not minimum neither maximum) point of $f(x)$ while $ f'(c) \not= 0 $ ?
if so, when is this the case ?

**Edit**: Edited bad translation from hebrew to english, changed saddle point to inflection point

Comment: "Saddle point" doesn't make sense for a function of one variable

Comment: A saddle point is by definition a stationary point, so that can't be the case,

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Of course. Consider $f(x)=\sin x$ defined in the real line. It has an inflection point at $x=0$, but $ f'(0) \neq 0$.

And there are, likewise, examples where $f'(c)$ *is* 0. For example, $f(x)=x^3$ has an inflection point at $x=0$.

Comment: @dhadas Sure. I suggest that if you find the answers on MSE that have the info you are looking for, accept them by clicking the check mark next to the answer (or if you feel your problem was only partially answered, asking more questions until you can understand the solution fully)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, saddle point means $f$ at $\vec{x}$ is having a local minimum in one variable and a local maximum in another. Hence, it requires at least 2 variables and is impossible to have in 1-D.

Comment: thank you, wrong translation from hebrew, corrected the question.